# Simple check for projected crs

Tags: python, geopandas, coordinate-systems

How can I easily check if a crs is a projected one for geopandas ?

Basically a function:

```
is_projected_crs(crs)
```

returning True or False.

I need that because I am writing some code to avoid the warning from geopandas :

```
Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'area' are likely incorrect. Use 'GeoSeries.to_crs()' to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`crs` comes with an [`is_projected`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/dev/api/crs/crs.html#pyproj.crs.CRS.is_projected) property:

```py
import geopandas

gdf = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path("nybb"))
print(gdf.crs, gdf.crs.is_projected)
# epsg:2263 True

gdf = gdf.to_crs(4326)
print(gdf.crs, gdf.crs.is_projected)
# EPSG:4326 False
```